Are 96V lead acid batteries a thing?
In the context of renewable energy grids (eg large-scale PV), I've seen people use 12V, 24V, and 48V batteries. I haven't seen 96V batteries.
I'm wondering, as things continue to scale-up to large-scale grid-tied PV plants or other grid battery systems, do engineers make use of large 96V lead acid batteries? What about 192V batteries.
Do they exist? If not, why?

you can make a 96 V battery yourself

One concern is that up to 48 V, the risk of electric shock to people working on the system is very unlikely. Above 48 V, safety standards typically require additional precautions to prevent shocks.

Lead acid batteries are all made up of 2V cells, combine as many as you want. 12V and 24V are convenient voltages for the motor industry, which is the traditional mass market for them but 6V has been used as well.

FWIW my 5kWh Li-ion battery is sitting at 53V.  That's modular, with symmetrical interconnect cables. The  connectors are rather like chunky versions of shrouded banana plugs, because they can  be live on plug or socket.  You'd have a job to get a screwdriver in there, let alone a finger.  In a grid-connected domestic solar setup the panel strings can be over 200VDC, whenever there's light on them.  That leads to some regulatory issues, safe ways of breaking contact, and lots of labels

When you have a few tons of lead-acid batteries, maintenance is a serious issue: C.F. 'O' Class Submarines - Electrical Systems.

Datacenter UPS have batteries at 480 VDC nominal.

@AndrewMorton that seems surprisingly high.  360V DC could be fed directly into a PSU designed for 240V AC avoiding the need for inverters.  But maybe I'm not thinking about the overall power conversion on a big enough scale.

Lead-acid batteries 96V 48x7PzS735 "Applications: forklifts, aerial platforms, scrubbers, sweepers and more"

TLDR: Systems that use more than 12V or 24V do so because they need a lot of power. High power systems need big batteries. Big batteries are expensive. And, big expensive batteries usually are assembled from individually replaceable 2V cells.

48V and lower is considered safe. Which means the regulatory and compliance is relaxed. At 96V and above, certification would be required in most countries. This slows down wide-spread adoption for higher DC voltages. Also, prior to renewable energy trends, 12V and 24V appliances and equipment were long established so the adoption was trivial. 48V systems are rare but are slowly gaining popularity. For example, try finding 48V inverters and appliances. Not many choices, right? Now look at equivalent 12V/24V devices - everyone sells them. Electric vehicles, on the other hand, do use much higher voltage battery packs. Part of this is due to efficiency (you can use smaller wires and cut down cost and weight). Also, EV market was new, so these vehicles had to run through safety and compliance testing anyway, so why not start with high voltage DC? It's not like there was "EV infrastructure" that existed before debut.

48V is very popular for telecom equipment but other than that, yeah. Maybe there are some other specific commercial niches but very little end-consumer stuff.

There's little point in making 96 or 192 V batteries available. Too high for safety, too low for efficiency. Its marketing niche does not exist.
48 V is low enough to be 'touch safe' for most jurisdictions, 96 V not so. So it is already too high to be 'safe'.
EVs and home battery packs are now popularising electronics for DC voltages in the 600 V to 1000 V range, for the efficiency of dealing with lower current.


do engineers make use of large 96V lead acid batteries? What about 192V batteries.
Do they exist? If not, why?

Short answer: yes, they exist, although they are rare.  Typically they are found in the DC power supplies used in electrical sub-stations; the primary purpose of these DC power supplies is to power the fault protection systems (sometimes called "fault protection relays").
Longer answer:
These batteries provide power backup in case the AC supply fails (the AC supply feeds the AC-DC converter).  When a major electrical fault occurs, the AC supply to the substation becomes very unstable, causing the output of the AC-DC converter to fail - that is when the battery becomes absolutely essential to ensure the continuing smooth operation of the fault protection system.
A good battery could mean the difference between a substation gracefully handling a fault as it was designed to do, or exploding and burning to the ground, and plunging a large section of the grid into darkness.
The Case for Lead-Acid
Why are lead-acid batteries used rather than newer battery technologies like lithium?  Because lead-acid batteries have proven themselves in this application for over 100 years, and the features that make lithium attractive for transport applications (EVs), such as lightweight and high power density, have no benefit in this application: there is plenty of room in a sub-station for a large & heavy lead-acid battery; reducing the size and weight of the battery is not attractive enough to overcome the perceived short-comings of lithium.
The companies that operate the AC grid and transmission systems are very conservative, they do not jump on the latest technology fad;  all equipment they adopt must be put through very rigorous testing, a process that can take years.  Furthermore, the cost of the DC power supply and its back-up battery is tiny compared to the cost of the substation, so there is little financial incentive to change from a technology that has proven itself over many decades.  Besides, the old-fashioned lead-acid is often the lowest-cost option.
The other benefit of lead-acid is simplicity & flexibility.  The charger can be quite simple, and does not require the sophisticated "battery management system" that most lithium batteries require.  Unlike lithium, lead-acid batteries are quite forgiving, they don't need individual cell "charge balancing", so you can connect the charger and load directly in parallel with the two ends of the battery string.
Flexibility: One can string together as many lead-acid battery cells as one likes - within reasonable limits, such as voltage limits and fault current limits - provided that all cells are the same make & model.
In comparison, most lithium batteries come in pre-engineered modules where several bare lithium cells are packaged up into a module that has all the equipment necessary to properly manage lithium cells.  Typically a user has to adhere to strict rules regarding how these modules can be arranged and used.  If a single lithium cell fails, usually the entire module has to be replaced - at a significantly higher cost compared to that of a single cell.
Typical Sub-Station DC Power Supply
Typically the entire system is floating with respect to earth, or more accurately, connected to earth via a high resistance, so the positive and negative DC terminals are usually balanced at half the total battery voltage above and below earth.  If an earth fault occurs the entire system just "floats" as required without tripping breakers, and the current in the resistor R2 can be used to detect an out-of-balance state for alarm purposes.  A second earth fault on a different node, however will cause heavy current to flow, so breakers are required, shown as CB1 in my diagram (sorry, the editor did not have a 2-pole MCCB).

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

"The Case for Lead-Acid" is a bit of an odd section. If you're after a heavy battery that's been around for a long time and is incredibly durable, I don't understand why you'd choose Lead-Acid instead of NiFe. Nickle-Iron batteries cost a bit more, but they've been around  for longer, last 3x longer (at least), and they're even more forgiving and easier to charge than lead-acid...

@MichaelAltfield  Yes, I am aware of the Ni-Fe battery (based on Edison's design, if I recall), however, I have not had any direct experience with them, nor have I seen them advertised or used in my part of the world (Australia).  I have, however, had over 10 years of field experience with lead-acid batteries both flooded-plate and immobilised electrolyte (gel) in sub-station and other stationary applications.   On paper, they do certainly look like a good candidate for stationary applications.

@MichaelAltfield Reading from Wikipedia: "Edison's batteries were profitably made from about 1903 to 1972 by the Edison Storage Battery Company in West Orange, New Jersey. In 1972 the battery company was sold to the Exide Battery Corporation, which discontinued the product in 1975. The battery was widely used for railroad signaling, forklift, and standby power applications."   Do you know of any manufacturers that are currently making Ni-Fe batteries?

@MichaelAltfield  Do you have any info to share about this company:  https://encell.com/products/

I've never heard of Encell or Fused Iron batteries. As you said, it's better to be conservative and "not jump on the latest technology fad." But there are a number of manufactures of Nickle-Iron batteries in China today. Here's one https://seawill.en.alibaba.com/

See also What's the benefit of 24V over 12V in solar and charging?

125 VDC nominal battery systems (60 cells × about 2.1 V/cell open-circuit) are common in substation switchgear environments and 125 VDC is a standard control power voltage for switchgear circuit breakers and their protective relays.
Here's an excerpt from Eaton 38kV class switchgear catalog showing typical control voltages used:

You would find similar choices for switchgear operating in the 600V, 5kV, and 15kV classes.  (Probably higher voltage classes as well, but I've never specified product above the 38 kV class.)
In this application, battery is used as a standby source when grid power is down, to open or close the circuit breakers, and maintain control functions, so it's not typically taking power directly from a PV system.  Somewhere between a grid-scale PV system and retail electricity customers, there's certain to be some systems like this.

We used to manufacture and supply a "120V" DC charging system, which could also be used with 96V and 56V systems.
We no longer do so because of the cost of 3rd-party laboratory certification, for safety and emissions standards, required for sale in our market.
For various reasons, it is desirable to have a battery voltage close to the maximum power point voltage of a solar string. Series strings require less wiring so are cheaper than parallel solar arrays. But that is handled by the use of voltage transformation in MPPT systems.
Generally it is desirable to operate battery banks in series rather than in parallel. So there was a demand for High Voltage battery systems.  But not enough demand to justify the large certification costs.
Note that High Voltage DC supplies are more problematic than AC supplies at the same voltage -- I can strike an arc and do welding off our solar panels, which you can't do off of normal house wiring.

For your last point about arching, here is a nice demonstration of how AC arcs are self-terminating when the voltage goes through the zero-point, while DC arcs are not: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zez2r1RPpWY
